# How to use webpack with babel-loader and flow

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, flowtype, babel-loader

I'm struggling with what I feel shouldn't be too hard of a setup.
I want these three technologies to work together:

- webpack to bundle code
- babel so that I'm able to write modern JavaScript
- flow because type checking is helpful just like tests and linter

I've already gone trough several setups of this but none of the articles I've found on the web appears to be helpful.

---

I've defined 3 scripts in my `package.json`, `run`, `flow` and `build`.
Typechecking with `yarn run flow` works perfectly, and so does executing the script trough `babel-node` using `yarn run start`.

But when I execute `yarn run build` the following error appears trough webpack:

```
$ ./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js
Hash: 207d42dac5784520fc99
Version: webpack 3.10.0
Time: 49ms
    Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
bundle.js  2.65 kB       0  [emitted]  main
   [0] ./src/main.js 181 bytes {0} [built] [failed] [1 error]

ERROR in ./src/main.js
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (3:5)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| // @flow
|
| type Foo = {
|   foo: string,
| };
error Command failed with exit code 2.
```

It appears to me that the type annotations don't get removed correctly at the right point. Sadly this also happend if I specify the babel options in webpack directly as opposed to the `.babelrc`.

This currently defeats me in bundling up a bunch of `.js` files whilst using flow and while I found several plugins that supposedly strip flow annotations simply using the `flow` preset is what flowtype.org appears to recommend.

---

For reproducibillity, my project files look like this:

**package.json**:

```
{
  …
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-flow": "^6.23.0",
    "flow-bin": "^0.60.1",
    "webpack": "^3.9.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js",
    "start": "./node_modules/babel-cli/bin/babel-node.js src/main.js",
    "flow": "./node_modules/flow-bin/cli.js"
  }
}
```

**.flowconfig**:

```
[include]
./src

[ignore]

[libs]

[lints]

[options]
```

**.babelrc**:

```
 {
   "presets": ["env", "flow"]
 }
```

**webpack.config.js**:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: [
      path.resolve('./src/'),
      'node_modules',
    ],
    extensions: ['.js'],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: '/.js$/',
        loader: 'babel-loader',
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

**src/main.js**:

```
// @flow

type Foo = {
  foo: string,
};

const defaultFoo: Foo = {
  foo: 'bar',
};

console.log(defaultFoo);
```

Comment: Try to specify presets in loader options in webpack.config: `test: '/.js$/', use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['env', 'flow',]
          }
        }`

Comment: I've tried that (before and again now), and I get the same error. I've also tried using only the `flow` preset without `env` or switching their order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Download the relevant presets and add them to the webpack.config.js as follows:

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
      use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'stage-0', 'react']
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Yes, but also no:
You pointed me into the right direction and so I managed to solve the problem. It was twofold however:
1. Indeed the `use: { loader: … }` setting, that was mentioned as well in a comment above was a big part.
2. Also running `yarn outdated` I discovered that I could update some packets, and after doing so things work as hoped for. I don't even need to specify the `query´ for babel outside of `.babelrc`.

As a bonus: Things are now working using only the `env` and `flow` presets.

Comment: @JakobRunge Can you please mention complete changes you did?